# How to secure and retrieve string data with a consistent length using encryption and decryption in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, c#-4.0, data-comparison

We aspire to achieve encryption and decryption in a way that ensures the length of the encrypted result aligns with the length of the original data. How can this objective be accomplished in .NET code?

For example:

string chars = "abcdeABCDE12345";
int resLen = 6;

String to encrypt:: Hello Word!

Result: CE1b5h

Comment: Why do you want to do this? What do you hope to achieve? Many methods need some type of Initialization Vector, and block based methods would round up the size. If you need some special, uncommon, solution you should probably explain what it is you are doing.

Comment: There is already an answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985830/how-do-i-encrypt-a-string-and-get-a-equal-length-encrypted-string

Comment: @JonasH I want to encrypt data which have data length same as the length of input string ,Input string may contains characters, numeric or any special characters

Comment: Which length do you mean? That of the ciphertext itself, the (e.g. Base64) encoded ciphertext or the length including necessary extra data such as IV and authentication tag? If it's only about the former: Any stream cipher mode (like CFB from the answer, although this is probably not the best choice) generates a ciphertext with the plaintext size.

Comment: @NotARobot If the input data is 'abcdef' and has a length of 6, then the encrypted data will also have the same length

Comment: Note that traditional encryptions use bytes and not strings, so an encoding comes into play (which performs the string-to-byte conversion). Example: The string `abcdef` is UTF-8 encoded 6 bytes long, but the string `abcd€f` is 8 bytes long. Therefore, specifying a length without encoding is incomplete. You may be referring to [format-preserving encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Format-preserving_encryption).

Comment: @NotARobot Is there any data encryption technique is there  in which encrypted data will also have the same data length?

Comment: You seem to be missing the point. From your example it appears that you want the output to be a human-readable string. Is that actually a requirement?

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk            No. Output may contain special character also fine for me

Comment: If you have a text A, this must be converted into a byte sequence B before encryption using a charset encoding (such as UTF-8). As a text character generally maps to several bytes, the encoding changes the length, i.e. the lengths of A and B differ. The encryption provides a ciphertext C, which also is a byte sequence. In the case of a stream cipher mode (such as CTR), the lengths of B and C are identical,...

Comment: ...in the case of a block cipher mode (such as CBC), C is longer than B (by a maximum of one block size, i.e. 16 bytes for AES). If you want to convert C into a string D, you need a binary-to-text encoding (like Base64) which increases the length (by 33% for Base64). So you see that there are four generally different lengths associated with A, B, C and D, which is why your question is imprecise. You need to specify which length you mean.

Comment: @NotARobot For instance, if the input string is "abcdef" with a length of 6 characters, the desired output string should also have a length of 6 characters.

Comment: With the usual algorithms such as AES, this is generally not possible for the reasons described. Maybe format preserving encryption is an option for you (see link in one of my previous comments).

Answer (score 0):

It's possible with AES CFB mode.

Simple implementation:

```cs
    static byte[] Encrypt(string plainText, byte[] key, byte[] iv)
    {
        using var aes = Aes.Create();
        aes.Key = key;
        aes.IV = iv;
        aes.Mode = CipherMode.CFB;
        aes.Padding = PaddingMode.None;

        var encryptor = aes.CreateEncryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV);

        using var msEncrypt = new MemoryStream();
        using (var csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        {
            using var swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt);
            swEncrypt.Write(plainText);
        }
        return msEncrypt.ToArray();
    }

    static byte[] Decrypt(byte[] cipherText, byte[] key, byte[] iv)
    {
        using var aes = Aes.Create();
        aes.Key = key;
        aes.IV = iv;
        aes.Mode = CipherMode.CFB;
        aes.Padding = PaddingMode.None;

        var decryptor = aes.CreateDecryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV);

        using var msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(cipherText);
        using var csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read);
        using var msDecrypted = new MemoryStream();
        csDecrypt.CopyTo(msDecrypted);
        return msDecrypted.ToArray();
    }
```

Usage:

```cs
var original = "Secret secret string";

using var aes = Aes.Create();
aes.GenerateKey();
aes.GenerateIV();

var encrypted = Encrypt(original, aes.Key, aes.IV);
var decrypted = Decrypt(encrypted, aes.Key, aes.IV);
```

Note:

That solution encrypts and decrypts to bytes array, if your goal is to get a string you can convert it by `Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes)`

Comment: If the input data is 'abcdef' and has a length of 6, it is possible to achieve that the encrypted data will also have the same length

Comment: `using var srDecrypt = new StreamReader(csDecrypt); return Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(srDecrypt.ReadToEnd());` is not correct, that will take the encrypted bytes as if they are valid UTF8 which they might not be. Also inefficient. Instead just do `return msDecrypt.ToArray();` or just return the stream

Comment: You've thrown away the IV, so this won't work in the real world. In your example the encryption and decryption occur in the same run of the program so you keep the IV around, but in real life decryption occurs some unspecified time after encryption.

Comment: @PraveenKumar CFB mode allows you to get the same amount of bytes after encryption/decryption

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk probably I don't understand you, but you just can store the IV somewhere as well as the Key. Because you will need them both for decryption. Another way is to generate the IV from the Key.